# PulseAudio doesn't start in Ubuntu Server 18.04 guest (VBox) and not in Windows 10 host

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, audio, ubuntu-18.04, pulse-audio

Currently I'm working on a Ubuntu Server 18.04 (no UI) in a VirtualBox. What I'd like to do is play audio files on my VirtualBox and listen to them on my Windows 10 host. I installed and configured PulseAudio for this on both systems. Unfortunately PulseAudio doesn't work and I'm not able to hear sounds on my host that I'm playing on the Virtualbox.

I configured PulseAudio on Windows 10 based on this post https://parseq.co.uk/wordpress/archives/setting-up-pulseaudio-1-0-beta-for-windows#comment-7788.

When I try to run PulseAudio with CMD in Windows, I get the following error:

```
D:\x\x\x\PulseAudio-1.1\bin>pulseaudio.exe -p "D:\x\x\x\PulseAudio-1.1\lib\pulse-1.1\modules" -nF "D:\x\x\x\PulseAudio-1.1\etc\pulse\default.pa"
W: [(null)] pulsecore/core-util.c: Secure directory creation not supported on Win32.
W: [(null)] pulsecore/core-util.c: Secure directory creation not supported on Win32.
W: [(null)] pulsecore/core-util.c: Secure directory creation not supported on Win32.
E: [(null)] pulsecore/pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [(null)] daemon/main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
```

On my Ubuntu guest PulseAudio doesn't work either. Should I change some configurations on this side as well? Or is something else happening?

```
x:~$ pulseaudio --start
x:~$ systemctl --user status pulseaudio.socket
● pulseaudio.socket - Sound System
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.socket; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: service-start-limit-hit) since Tue 2019-05-07 08:35:09 CEST; 2h 41min ago
   Listen: /run/user/1000/pulse/native (Stream)

May 07 08:35:07 x systemd[1401]: Listening on Sound System.
May 07 08:35:09 x systemd[1401]: pulseaudio.socket: Failed with result 'service-start-limit-hit'.
x:~$ systemctl --user restart pulseaudio.service
Job for pulseaudio.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl --user status pulseaudio.service" and "journalctl --user -xe" for details.
x:~$ systemctl --user status pulseaudio.service
● pulseaudio.service - Sound Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-05-07 11:17:25 CEST; 2min 59s ago
  Process: 23012 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 23012 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 07 11:17:25 x systemd[1401]: Failed to start Sound Service.
May 07 11:17:25 x systemd[1401]: pulseaudio.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
May 07 11:17:25 x systemd[1401]: pulseaudio.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
May 07 11:17:25 x systemd[1401]: Stopped Sound Service.
May 07 11:17:25 x systemd[1401]: pulseaudio.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
May 07 11:17:25 ubuntuVmRomanPc systemd[1401]: pulseaudio.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 07 11:17:25 x systemd[1401]: Failed to start Sound Service.


x:~$ systemctl --user status pulseaudio.service
● pulseaudio.service - Sound Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-05-07 11:17:25 CEST; 2min 59s ago
  Process: 23012 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 23012 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 07 11:17:25 x systemd[1401]: Failed to start Sound Service.
May 07 11:17:25 x systemd[1401]: pulseaudio.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
May 07 11:17:25 x systemd[1401]: pulseaudio.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
May 07 11:17:25 x systemd[1401]: Stopped Sound Service.
May 07 11:17:25 x systemd[1401]: pulseaudio.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
May 07 11:17:25 x systemd[1401]: pulseaudio.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 07 11:17:25 x systemd[1401]: Failed to start Sound Service.
x:~$ journalctl --user -xe
--
-- Unit UNIT has failed.
--
-- The result is RESULT.
May 07 11:17:25 x systemd[1401]: pulseaudio.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
May 07 11:17:25 x systemd[1401]: pulseaudio.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
-- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Automatic restarting of the unit UNIT has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
May 07 11:17:25 x systemd[1401]: Stopped Sound Service.
-- Subject: Unit UNIT has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit UNIT has finished shutting down.
May 07 11:17:25 x systemd[1401]: Starting Sound Service...
-- Subject: Unit UNIT has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit UNIT has begun starting up.
May 07 11:17:25 x pulseaudio[23012]: E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
May 07 11:17:25 x pulseaudio[23012]: E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
May 07 11:17:25 x systemd[1401]: pulseaudio.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 07 11:17:25 x systemd[1401]: pulseaudio.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 07 11:17:25 x systemd[1401]: Failed to start Sound Service.
-- Subject: Unit UNIT has failed
```

I looked around for a solution but I haven't been able to find the right one. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

In the end I found solutions for my problems.

On my Windows host system I had to delete the PID file that was created after I started PulseAudio. This file can be hard to find, use the file explorer if you can’t find it. The PID file was stored in a random folder on my system.
When I start PulseAudio again I use the following command so I won't run into this problem anymore: pulseaudio.exe --use-pid-file=false –D

PulseAudio worked on the Ubuntu guest system after I installed PulseAudio again.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the PID file on my Windows 10 desktop under:
C:\Users\MyUser.pulse\MyComputername-runtime\pid

When I deleted the PID file, I was able to start pulseaudio successfully.

Comment: In my case it was under `C:\Users\%USER%\.config\pulse\%HOSTNAME%-runtime>\pid`